# Cron notification not getting sent when the job takes a long time to finish

Tags: cron

I've added the following to crontab. It runs every 30 minutes well. I've observed one odd thing though that the email is sent whenever the cron finishes within few minutes and Not when it takes 3 minutes+. Are there such restrictions? Is there a way to tell crontab to wait till the job finishes and send out the entire text that the process outputs?

```
MAILTO=notifs@mydevdomain.com
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/z/process_batch.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, cron will redirect all output and collect that and after the job has finished, the output get's sent to what is in MAILTO. And that's regardless from how long this may take.

Problems over here are usually:

The job takes more than 30 min (your interval) to run and cron is starting a second instance of your batch. You need to deal with that.

The job never finishes and hangs, this might cause some zombie processes in your system and in certain situations may also block cron from working properly.

So, if the job is running longer than 3 mins and after it actually has finished, no email has been sent by cron seems not to be a cron issue but merely related to your batch php.

Comment: That's true, another job starts while the first one is still running and then looks at a database lock and exits. So, this kills the first one? Isn't it kind of independent? My knowledge of crons and unix system pretty minimal.

Comment: Actually we have a quite similar situation and we solved that by letting the second one look for a semaphore (file in /tmp) and exiting immediately without accessing the database. Thus preventing from having two instances at a time. I therefor enclosed all jobs in to a bash script handling the lock and kicking off the real job.

Comment: Can you share the script if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just as some hints:

```
-------------%<--------------------
...
# name of the task, param 1
export LOCKEXT=$1; shift
export LOCK=/tmp/cron_lock.$LOCKEXT
...

# catch on external signals
trap "rm $LOCK" 10 11 15

...

if [ -f $LOCK ]
then
    echo "`date`: still running: `ls -l $LOCK` ...."
    exit 0
else
    touch $LOCK
fi

.....
# run your task
....

rm -f $LOCK

-------------->%------------------
```

Comment: will be my first shell experiment. I'll give it a try.